# Laravel validation if input is not empty required_with

Tags: laravel, validation, required

I'm using laravel and i have a request form with rule like this:

```
    'postal_code1' => 'required',
    'postal_code2' => 'required_with:postal_code1|numeric',
```

and some html

```
<input type="text" name="postal_code1" />
<input type="text" name="postal_code2" />
```

The trouble i met that when i don't fill the `postal_code1`, 
I receive the error

> Postal_code2 must be a number

How do **numeric** rule run only if the input is filled?

I tried the sometimes rule:

```
'postal_code2' =>'sometimes|required_with:postal_code1|numeric'
```

But not working

Comment: here you add postal_code1 required then empty is not allowd for postal_code1

Comment: 'postal_code1' => 'required',
 'postal_code2' => 'bail|required_with:postal_code1|numeric',

Comment: @JinalSomaiya: because i want both of input required but error message is display once time only.

Comment: @SachinAghera not working :((

Comment: if you need both field required then why you not use simple required?

Comment: @SachinAghera because i want the error message like "postal_code is required" display only once time

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, it's very easy. Change the rule as below:

```
'postal_code2' => 'nullable|required_with:postal_code1|numeric'
```

Comment: That's the solution but for example if both 'postal_code2' and 'postal_code1' are nullable validation not passes.